# Error con array e if anidados

Tags: java

He hecho un trabajo para clase con un montón de ifs anidados, el problema es que tengo que meter un bucle for para que me recorra un array comprobando si el dni está repetido, pero tengo tantas anidaciones que al cerrar el for o lo rompo del else o el bucle se pasa. ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo sin deshacer demasiado la estructura inicial? (El problema está después del comentario "comprobamos que el DNI esté o no en el array"

```
    do {
        /*Mostramos el menú*/
        System.out.println("VENTA DE ENTRADAS");
        System.out.println("1. HACER RESERVAS");
        System.out.println("2. VER RESERVAS");
        System.out.println("3. SALIR");
        opc = teclado.nextInt();
        /*Diferentes opciones*/
        switch (opc) {
            case 1:
                /*Primero comprobamos que haya entradas disponibles*/
                if (disp > 0) {
                    System.out.println("¿Cuántas entradas quiere?");
                    ent = teclado.nextInt();
                    /*Comprobamos que no pida más de 4*/
                    if (ent <= 4) {
                        /*Comprobamos que hay tantas disponibles como pide*/
                        if (ent <= disp) {
                            System.out.println("Introduzca su DNI");
                            dni = teclado.nextInt();
                            /*Comprobamos que el DNI esté o no en el array*/

                                if (dni == a1[i]) {
                                    /*Si lo está, comprobamos cuántas entradas ha pedido anteriormente*/
                                    resul = a2[i] + ent;
                                    /*Si la suma de la cantidad que pide es igual o menor a 4, se suma*/
                                    if (resul <= 4) {
                                        resul = a2[i];
                                        /*Se le resta la compra al total para que se reflejen las entradas disponibles*/
                                        disp = disp - ent;
                                    }
                                    /*Si el dni es nuevo, se añade al array 1 con su compra de entradas en el array2*/
                                } else {
                                    a1[i] = dni;
                                    a2[i] = ent;
                                    disp = disp - ent;
                                }
                                /*Si el disponible de entradas es inferior a la petición, damos error*/
                            }else {
                        System.out.println("NO QUEDAN SUFICIENTES ENTRADAS DISPONIBLES");
                    }
                            /*Si inentan comprar más de 4 entradas por persona, damos error*/
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("NO SE PUEDEN COMPRAR MÁS DE 4 ENTRADAS POR PERSONA");
                        }
                        /*Si las entradas están agotadas, lo indicamos al pulsar "compra de entradas"*/
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("ENTRADAS AGOTADAS");
                    }
                    break;


        case 2:
                /*Mostramos las entradas disponibles*/
              System.out.println("Entradas disponibles: " + disp); 
              /*Bucle para que muestre todos los DNI con sus compras*/
              for(i=0; i<12;i++){
                System.out.println("DNI: " + a1[i] + " " + "Entradas"+ a2[i]);
                break;
                }
            }
         }while (opc != 3);

    }
}
```

Comment: Comentas algo sobre un for, pero en la zona del código donde dices que esta el problema no veo ningún for. Aun así comprueba bien que los else esten relacionados con los ifs correspondientes. Y si no, usando el debug mode deberías poder ver el error.

Comment: La intención es ponerlo aquí
for(i=0; i<12;i++){
                                if (dni == a1[i]) {
                                    /*Si lo está, comprobamos cuántas entradas ha pedido anteriormente*/
                                    resul = a2[i] + ent; }

El problema es que corta el else que tiene ese if, y si los separo y los convierto en ifs independientes al añadir el resultado "resul = a2[i] + ent;" si está dentro del for se copia en todas las casillas del array y si está fuera no puede comprobar que el dni ya esté metido

Answer (score 0):

Es dificil contestar tu pregunta, ya que no definis cual es la estructura del array. Pero por lo que entendí:
1. Llega un array (a1) con todos los dni
2. Se comprueba si el dni que ingreso el usuario ya esta acá (Estas preguntando como hacer esta parte)
3. Si esta el dni, se le asignan ciertas entradas, caso contrario, se guarda el dni en a1 y se le asigna una cantidad de entradas.

Para comprobar si cierto numero esta dentro de un array necesitamos recorrer cada punto del array y compararlo con el dni que va a ser ingresado

```
 for(x=0;x<a1.length;x++){
 // Pasa por cada elemento del array
        if (dni== a1[x]) {
        //pregunta si el elemento que ingreso el usuario se encuentra en este item del array

        //y aca ya pones lo que quieras que haga este codigo
        //EJ:
            elNumeroEsta = true;
        //Y despues usar esta variable para elegir que if se ejecuta
        }
 }
```

entonces tu codigo original quedaria algo así

```
 if (elNumeroEsta) { //<----SOLO CAMBIE ESTA LINEA

     resul = a2[i] + ent;
     // SI ACA NECESITARAS EL NUMERO DE ITEM EN DONDE SE ENCUENTRA ESE DNI PODES CREAR OTRA VARIABLE EN EL FOR Y GUARDARLA AHÍ

         if (resul <= 4) {
             resul = a2[i];

             disp = disp - ent;
         }

     } else {
     //...
     }
 }
```

Comment: Si! Lo entendiste bien. Con el array no sé a qué te refieres, sólo los declaramos porque es lo único que nos enseñaron de momento, las variables las inicialice así: 
int opc, i = 0;
        long disp = 12, ent, dni, resul = 0;
        long a1[] = new long[12];
        long a2[] = new long[12];

Comment: Añadí una variable boolean y modifiqué el código, pero no va
/*Comprobamos que el DNI esté o no en el array*/
                                for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                                    if (dni == a1[i]) {
                                        num = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                /*Si lo está, comprobamos cuántas entradas ha pedido anteriormente*/
                                if (num = true) {
                                    resul = a2[i] + ent;
                                }